# Vertical line in middle of the screen

Tags: lumia, screen

Has someone experienced a vertical line appearing in middle of the screen? On Microsoft Lumia 435 mobile phone.
The line seems to appear after using some time the phone, and  enlarge over time.
Is there a solution for this bug? Thanks.

Comment: If you take a screenshot, does this line appear when you view the screenshot elsewhere?

Comment: @RowlandShaw Good advice! Just now I cannot try this because after rebooting the phone the line disappeared.

Comment: Which Lumia phone are you using? Which version of Windows Phone/Windows Mobile are you using?

Comment: @RowlandShaw Indeed, the vertical line doesn't appears on the screenshot!

Comment: @ThisWillDoIt Lumia 435. Edited!

Answer (score 1):

As the line doesn't appear on screenshots, it appears to not be a software issue, and your handset may have developed a fault - I would suggest taking it to your local friendly repair centre for repair/replacement (subject to warranty, etc.)

Comment: Thank you ! But this is the problem, which software issue ? ... The phone was already sent to the centre but they haven't found the problem (they pretend the line didn't appeared -- indeed it not always).